# invoke WCF service method from web browser

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure, web

I want to run my service from the web browser: `http://localhost:443/TestService//RunTest/data/test`
It doesn`t work for me

```
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://localhost:443 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

How to solve that - redefine endpoint - how?
The WCF service:

```
//TestService.svc.cs
public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public string RunTest(string data)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", data);
        }
}
//ITestService.cs
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/RunTest/data/{data}")]
string RunTest(string data)
{
     return string.Format("You entered: {0}", proxyDomain);
}
//Web.config
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration introduced
         in .NET Framework 4.5.1 -->
      <service
          name="TestService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:443/TestService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:443/TestService"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="ITestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Also when I run it  a WCF client is opened with  port 54388

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you wouldn't be able to test directly via the browser.
Instead you should use a WCF Test Client:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx

What you can do using your browser, is to see if you can reach the WSDL.
An example of a WSDL call in a browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/DecisionService/ws/PreTradeChecksRuleApp/1.0/PreTradeChecks/1.0?WSDL
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add/change the endpoint "binding" attribute to "webHttpBinding" like this:

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:443/TestService"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="ITestService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
```

Or

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:443/TestService"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="ITestService" />
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:443/TestService/web"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="ITestService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
```

**In Both Cases you Have to Add:**

```
<behaviors>
...
<endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
...
</behaviors>
```

**notes:**

1) You have to add the attribute behaviorConfiguration to the webBinding and Add the behavior configuration

2) In the second solution, You have to change the name of the baseAddress because you can't have two endpoints configured to the same baseAddress (**if anyone knows how to do it, please it would help me too**)

Best Regards